# Fails running sample project with Broadcast Upload Extension on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, replaykit

I'm trying to make from scratch a simple iOS app with a `Broadcast Upload Extension`. The scope is just showing the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView`, start broadcasting and receive the audio & video samples in the upload extension.

This is the code for displaying the RPSystemBroadcastPickerView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let broadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(broadcastPicker)
    }
}
```

and I've added the `Broadcast Upload Extension` and `Broadcast Setup UI Extension` (which at this point seems I don't need it) to the targets. I'm running the app, then each extension on the device but doesn't seem to happen anything.

I've tried Twilio's sample code and it's working fine but I couldn't figure out why, seems like some missing configuration. Also worth mentioning I'm using XCode 12.0 and trying to run on device with iOS 14.

Will appreciate any lead. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated XCode version to 12.1 and it's working now.